# nextInt() following System.out.print()

Tags: java, printing

```
System.out.print("Please enter the first number >");
System.out.print("Please enter the second number >");
```

The above code snippet results in this output:

```
"Please enter the first number >Please enter the second number >"
```

While this code snippet:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter the first number >");
int num1 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter the second number >");
int num2 = kb.nextInt();
```

Results in this:

```
"Please enter the first number > 4"
"Please enter the second number > 5"
```

Why?

Normally using several `System.out.print()`'s in a row will result in text being printed out on the same line. But when using `nextInt()`; which skips over the carriage return control character, before the next `System.out.print()` the text is no longer printed on the same line.

Comment: what is this object kb ?

Comment: It was a Scanner class object, I forgot to include it. I've since edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt` don't skip over the carriage return control character but ignores it. Therefore, this carriage return came from you hitting the key "Enter" to confirm your integer input.

You didn't give object `kb` though, so it was my guess was that you were reading `stdin`.